# code to find 2nd largest no. (in C language)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, max

> Given a list of positive integers, find the 2nd largest integer.
>
> Note:
> **Usage of arrays is forbidden (only concepts until loops are allowed)**

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    int N, x, i, max2; //N = total no. of given numbers
    int max = INT_MIN;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x >= max)
            max = x;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x == max)
            continue;
        else if (x < max) {
            int max2 = INT_MIN;
            if (x >= max2)
                max2 = x;
        }
        printf("2nd largest no.= %d", max2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I did but this is not working as expected although no errors were thrown. Basically, I first found the largest number from the given list of numbers and then I was trying to find the largest number from the remaining no.s

what changes should I make in this code?
Also please suggest a better method for this problem (if any).

Comment: This code makes no sense at all.  Think about what it's doing:  The first loop reads an increasing sequence of numbers.  As soon as it reads a number that's less than the previous numbers, it exits.  At this point you've already lost:  (1) You have no idea how many numbers remain to be read (although you could get it from `i`), and (2) What if the very first number was the second-largest, and the second number was the largest?  The second-largest number is gone.  You can't get it back.  Game over.

Comment: If you want to find the X'th largest number, you must keep track of the (X-1)'th largest number. So for the second largest number you must also know the first largest number. For a small value of X, like two in your case, it's trivial to do in a single loop. For larger values of X you need an array to store all values, sort it, and then get the X:th value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong at least because you need to use only one sequence of entered data and consequently only one for loop.

Pay attention to that in this statement

```
printf("2nd largest no.= %d", max2);
```

there is used the variable `max2` declared in the outer block scope

```
int N, x, i, max2; //N = total no. of given numbers
```

It is not the same as the variable `max2` declared in this compound statement

```
  else if (x < max) {
        int max2 = INT_MIN;
        if (x >= max2)
            max2 = x;
    }
```

So in the call of `printf` there will be used the uninitialized variable `max2` declared in the outer block scope.

To discover the second largest number makes sense when it is assumed that it shall not be equal to the first largest number. More precisely the program searches the second greatest value among entered values.

Here is a demonstration program that solves the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n;

    if (scanf( "%u", &n ) == 1)
    {
        int first_max, second_max;
        int second_max_exists = 0;

        int value;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n && scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 && value > 0; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                first_max = value;
            }
            else if (first_max < value)
            {
                second_max = first_max;
                second_max_exists = 1;
                first_max = value;
            }
            else if (( value != first_max ) && ( ( second_max_exists == 0 ) || ( second_max < value ) ))
            {
                second_max = value;
                second_max_exists = 1;
            }
        }

        if ( second_max_exists ) printf( "2nd largest no.= %d\n", second_max );
        else puts( "There is no 2nd largest no." );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
10
1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 7
2nd largest no.= 5
```

Indeed the first largest number is equal to `7` and the second largest number is equal to `5`.

As you are expecting only positive numbers then you could allow the user to enter a sequence of positive numbers of any length until zero or a negative number will be entered.

In this case the program can look simpler as for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int first_max, second_max;
    int first_max_exists = 0, second_max_exists = 0;

    puts( "Enter a sequence of positive numbers (0 or negative number - exit)" );

    int value;

    while ( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1  && value > 0 )
    {
        if (first_max_exists == 0)
        {
            first_max = value;
            first_max_exists = 1;
        }
        else if (first_max < value)
        {
            second_max = first_max;
            second_max_exists = 1;
            first_max = value;
        }
        else if (( value != first_max ) && ( ( second_max_exists == 0 ) || ( second_max < value ) ))
        {
            second_max = value;
            second_max_exists = 1;
        }
    }

    if (second_max_exists) printf( "2nd largest no.= %d\n", second_max );
    else puts( "There is no 2nd largest no." );
}
```

Comment: @AllanWind Who did said that it is a positive number?:)

Comment: I kinda dig (like) the scanf() in the for condition :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work:

- you cannot parse the input twice. Even if you issued a `rewind(stdin)`, it would only work when input is redirected from a file, not when input comes from a character device such as the terminal, nor from a pipe.  You should modify the first loop to keep track of the 2 greatest values.
- `max2` is uninitialized.
- a new variable `max2` is defined inside the scope of the `if (x < max) {}` block, hiding the outer one (the technical term is *shadowing*).  The outer variable is never changed.

It is unclear whether you are expected to output the second largest distinct value or the largest value if it appears more than once.

Here is a modified version for the second largest distinct value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N, x, i;
    int max = 0;
    int max2 = 0;
    int has_max = 0;
    int has_max2 = 0;

    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
            break;
        if (!has_max) {
            has_max = 1;
            max = x;
        } else
        if (x > max) {
            has_max2 = 1;
            max2 = max;
            max = x;
        } else
        if (x < max && (!has_max2 || x > max2)) {
            has_max2 = 1;
            max2 = x;
        }
    }
    if (has_max2) {
        printf("2nd largest no.= %d\n", max2);
    } else {
        printf("no 2nd largest\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem description says positive integers.

Comment: @AllanWind: the above code still works if all  numbers are positive, as long as they are `<= INT_MAX`.  Using a different type (`unsigned` or even `unsigned long long`) may increase the maximum value but this issue seems beyond the skill level for this assignment as *only concepts until loops are allowed*.

Comment: I don't think you want to accept invalid input.  You can of course make the argument that the pre-condition was invalid and hence anything goes.

Comment: @AllanWind: The argument is valid: *Given a list of positive integers...*

Comment: @AllanWind: I deliberately accept negative numbers but removed some complexity as neither `<limits.h>` not `INT_MIN` are needed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you maintain the invariant than `max` is the largest number, and `max2` the 2nd largest number as you process each new element.  I would use an array instead of separate variables if it wasn't disallowed.

Initializing the two values to INT_MIN gets you in trouble if you don't read at least two elements.  As the problem description talks about "positive integers" it's also not valid input.  Likewise `0` is not a positive integer either so it's being ignored if entered (you could add an error message if you choose).

It's unclear from the problem description what the behavior should be for duplicates, say, if user enters 1, 1 is the 2nd largest value 1 or is there no 2nd largest values?  @chqrlie and @VladfromMoscow considers that possibility while my answers assumes that both the largest and 2nd largest number can be the same value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(unsigned *a, unsigned*b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main() {
    printf("n? ");
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(n < 2) {
        printf("n must be at least 2");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned max;
    unsigned max2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned v;
        do {
            if(scanf("%u", &v) != 1) {
                printf("scanf failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        } while(!v);
        if(!i)
            max = v;
        else if(i == 1 || v >= max2) {
            max2 = v;
            if(max < max2)
                swap(&max, &max2);
        }
    }
    printf("2nd largest: %u\n", max2);
}
```

example session:

```
n? 3
0
1
2
3
2nd largest: 2
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how duplicates are supposed to be handled, but the OP attempts to find the second largest distinct value.